# Is `go get` recursive? Aka: Are git submodules taken care of when installing a dependency from a git repository

Tags: git, go, dependencies, go-get

If I install a go dependency from a git repository and this git repository has git submodules, are there taken care of when installing the dependency with  `go get`?

I couldn't find an answer skimming and ctrl-f'ing [golang/go/../cmd/go/../get.go)](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/go/internal/modget/get.go). Before starting to test and potentially missing caveats I think it's good to ask people who might know this.

Comment: In contemporary Go, `go get` does not fetch any modules, it merely adds intent to use them to your module. Please read [this](https://go.dev/ref/mod#mod-commands).